# filtering event logs with specific TIME range of ANY day

Tags: powershell, windows-event-log, time, query, date

How can I query windows server events between two times of any day?
I have tried with PowerShell...

```
Get-EventLog -Logname xxxx -After 04:00:00 -Before 04:00:30
```

...but just returns today's events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find events between two times at any day we'll want to use a regex. Example code to find any event that happened between 04:00:00 and 04:29:59 of any day in the System log:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName System | ?{$_.TimeGenerated -match "04:[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]"}
```

Comment: Thanks Mikael, but how can I ask the same query for ANY day (if possible) in an elegant way?

Comment: Initial reply updated to actually answer the question.

Comment: @MikaelH, That's great. Can you explain more about the regex part (`04:[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]`)? for example if my time range is `04:00:55 - 05:12:03` then how to modify the regex?

Comment: @Tom, Each bracket represents the allowed range for a single character in the TimeGenerated field. For the first example given, I knew that we'll always want to look within hour number 4, i.e. "04". To also include events from hour number 5, we'd replace "04:" with "0[4-5]:". The next part of your request gets significantly more hairy: We'd need to program our "where" query ("?") to include only the last five seconds of the minute "4:00:", and only the first three seconds of the minute "5:12:".I'd define these non-general qualifications in "or", or "and not" clauses next to the main one.

Comment: @Tom, Just to illustrate my point, the first part of your query would look something like this:

Get-EventLog -LogName System | ?{$_.TimeGenerated -match "04:00:5[5-9]" -or $_.TimeGenerated -match "04:0[1-9]:\d\d" -or $_.TimeGenerated -match "04:[1-5][0-9]:\d\d"}

Comment: @Tom, Someone who is more fluent in regex could probably shorten that to a lovely unreadable chunk-o-chars, but I'm a simple man. :)