# Unix Sed time range parsing issue

Tags: sed

I have Hybris SAP application with console log.
The log format looks like this

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/28 17:17:19.969 |       <String>timestamp</String>
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/28 17:17:19.969 |       <String>1590700639952</String>
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/28 17:17:19.969 |     </entry>
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/28 17:17:19.969 |   </headers>
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/28 17:17:19.969 | </RequestDataVo>
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/28 17:17:19.969 | RAW RESPONSE: NULL
```

I need to extract time range

```
12 am to 1 am
```

trying to do bt this sed

```
sed -n '/2020\/05\/29 00:00:00/ , /2020\/05\/29 01:00:00/p'
```

but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You’ll want to use regular expressions, and you might want to try grep instead. The linked answer is for a PowerShell question, but the regex should be applicable to your problem: https://serverfault.com/a/951094/507179

Answer (score 0):

so I found the answer I'd like to share it
grep -E '^*2020/05/28 17:'